# fabric で、サーバ情報収集して、その結果を取得するには、

Tags: python, fabric

fabric で、遠隔のサーバにはいり、処理をしてその結果を持ち帰るにはどうするのがいいでしょうか？

やりたいことは、

１．遠隔サーバの特定のディレクトリに、特定のユーザでログインして、ローカルサーバのスクリプトを実する。
遠隔サーバには、スクリプトを置きたくありません。

２．実行結果を、ローカルサーバに移動して、実行結果を保存するために生成したファイルを消去する。

どうしても、fabric での解決をもとめているわけではないですが、fabric だと手間かけずにできそうなきがしたのです。

Answer (score 1):

fabricでということであれば、ローカルサーバのスクリプトをputしてリモートに配置して実行、実行結果をリモートからローカルへget、そしてリモートに置いたスクリプトを削除・・・みたいな流れでいかがでしょうか。

putとgetのサンプル fabfile.py
<引用サイト様：http://perezvon.hatenablog.com/entry/20091026/1256552181>

```
from fabric.api import local, put, get

def put_and_get():
local('date > /tmp/local.txt')
put('/tmp/local.txt', '/tmp/remote.txt')
get('/tmp/remote.txt', '/tmp/remote2.txt')
```

どのみち`ssh`することになるので、個人的には`expect`ですとか、`sshpass`なんかもおすすめです。

Answer (score 1):

単純にローカルのスクリプトをリモートで実行したいなら、sshを使えばいいです。

```
ssh user@host 'bash -s' < local_script.sh > results.txt
```

コマンドの引数を渡したいとか、環境変数を引き継ぎたいとかになると、もう一工夫必要でしょう。

fabricを使うなら,下のコードをfabfile.pyに保存して`fab remote:ホスト名,ローカルスクリプト名`として実行すれば動きます。

```
from fabric.api import run, settings

def remote(host, local_script):
    # read the local script
    with open(local_script, 'rb') as f:
        script = f.read()
    # run it on the remote host
    with settings(host_string=host):
        resp = run(script)
    # save the result into results.txt
    with open('results.txt', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp)
```